# ISAPI Rewrite - Helicon /user to /page.asp?username=user

Tags: url-rewriting, isapi-rewrite

Im trying to rewrite my url from this :

http://www.somedomain.com/User

to

http://www.somedomain.com/somepage.asp?Username=User

Where the =User in URL 2 is the same as the /User in URL 1. It would be great if it doesnt just redirect, but do the change in the background.

Im using Helicon ISAPI_Rewrite ver 3.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that to do a somedomain.com/user direction is possible, BUT it will mean that all requests will be send to your redirect, as somedomain.com/user and somedomain.com/page.asp will both be redirected. For this to work you will need to handle the requests to your redirect accordingly.

What I ended up doing, as this is MUCH less work, is to just redirect somedomain.com/user/username to the page I wanted to redirect to. the rule for this, looks like follow:

```
RewriteEngine Off
AllowOverride none

<VirtualHost somedomain.com>

    RewriteEngine on
    AllowOverride all

RewriteRule ^/user/(.*) /somepage.asp?UserName=$1

</VirtualHost>
```

Hope this helps someone.